# How to retrieve profile data from Linkedin

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I want to retrieve all public information of linkedin user for this I've used Javascript SDK something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: 'my key'
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: true
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);

    }
   function onLinkedInAuth() {
        IN.API.Profile("me").fields("id", "first-name", "last-name", "email-address"
        , "public-profile-url", "picture-url", "picture-urls::(original)", "headline", "summary", "location", "industry", "positions").result(displayProfiles);
    }
    // 2. Runs when the Profile() API call returns successfully
    function displayProfiles(profiles) {
        member = profiles.values[0];
        document.getElementById("profiles").innerHTML =
      "<p>" + member.id + "<br> " + member.firstName + "<br> " + member.lastName + "<br>" + member.emailAddress + "</p>"

       + "<br>" + member.industry + "</p>"
        + "<br>" + member.summary + "</p>";

        var positions = profiles.values[0].positions;
        var positionCount = positions._total;

        for(var i = 0; i < positionCount; i++) {
          var company = positions.values[i].company;
          var title = positions.values[i].title;
          document.getElementById("profiles").innerHTML += "<div >" + title + ", " + company.name + "</div>";
        }

    }
</script>
```

and in my body tag I've

```
   <body>

<script type="in/Login"></script>

<div id="profiles"></div>

</body>
```

It works fine as user now have to provide its credentials and I've saved all this information into my local DB.

**Now what I want is to retrieve data of same user after some time without user authentication, I just have to update my DB with user latest information from Linkedin. Since user have allowed access my site to get his profile, therefore I don't want user to bother again.I just wanted to update user info of my local DB without letting user know about it but only if user have allowed its access to me.**

thanks & regards,

Comment: what is the question here? how to use the linkedin api?
you can see the api document here: 
https://apigee.com/console/linkedin
or did you mean how token are used ?

Comment: I've already implemented linkedin api.. I just want to take all information from there and store in my local DB which I've also completed.. now what I want is to retrieve the same data of user without authentication of user.. I don't want to provide userID and Password again of linkedin to retrieve information from there so that I can update my local DB information

Comment: you are supposed to get a token when user authenticated, then you can query the api